# Javascript error suppression- unsure about the usage for window.onerror = function() in a particular context

Tags: javascript

I am experimenting with javascript error suppression (For research purposes).

```
<a class="test" onclick="window.onerror = function(){ return true;} alert(1);test(&quot;,&quot;)" 
href="#" role="button">test</a>
```

My aim is to run the alert() function despite test() being in error (passed parameter problem). The window.onerror statement doesn't catch and ignore the error, and I don't understand why.

Can someone explain the problem with this particular solution please?

Edit: Example 2 that also doesn't work:

```
<a class="test" onclick="alert(1); void(&quot;,&quot;)" href="#" role="button">test</a>
```

Edit: Example 3 that also doesn't work:

```
<a class="test" onclick="alert(1); &quot;,&quot;)" href="#" role="button">test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a parse error, and `window.onerror` can only trap runtime errors. By the way, it's weird to have `window.onerror` defined inside an onclick handler.

Comment: I see, thank you for answering. Is there a way to suppress parse errors in this context?

Comment: I don't think so. But why do you have that kind of error? Are you generating code dynamically?

Comment: Basically I am testing for injection into the onclick event. I can put some characters after alert(1). Putting "//" after would escape out all the rest of the JS, but these two characters are not allowed. See example 3- with no added characters, and example 2 where I tried to send the remainder to void (would only work without special characters between the brackets.